# I need to sort it out this quiz

Tags: javascript

my code is not working at all

I need to solve this quiz

question is write convertToString as function !

this function should convert to string from parameter

## ex )

```
let output = convertToString(120);
console.log(output); // --> '120'

let output2 = convertToString('hello');
console.log(output2); // --> 'hello'

let output3 = convertToString(true);
console.log(output3); // --> 'true'
```

### this is what I wrote

```
function convertToString(anything) {

  if (typeof anything === 'number' && typeof anything === 'boolean') {
    let ret = anything.toString()
  } else {
    return anything;
  }
  return ret1;
}

convertToString(120);
```

Comment: What is `ret1` ? Also `.toString()` can be called on *anything*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to convert anything is by making + operation with ""

```js
    function convertToString(anything) {
     return "" + anything
    }
    
    console.log(convertToString(12));
    console.log(convertToString(true));
    console.log(convertToString('hello'));
    console.log(convertToString(null));
    console.log(convertToString(undefined));
```

Answer (score 0):

Zero checks necessary.

```js
function convertToString(val) {
    return String(val);
    // or return val.toString();
    // or return '' + val;
}

console.log(convertToString(12));
console.log(convertToString(true));
console.log(convertToString('hello'));
```